# WebAPI, no Post

Tags: asp.net-web-api

WebAPI, I'm getting a HTTP 500 error. The alerts that I put in are firing correctly. But I put a breakpoint in the Post method in ProductsController.cs. It didn't stop at the breakpoint which seems to indicate that the routing wasn't right. My intention is to have the Post method add the new row to the array and have the new row displayed in the list. Can you help? Here is the current state of the code:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Default.aspx +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebAPISPA6.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            getProducts();

            $("#btn").on('click', function () {
                var prodDTO = {}
                alert('on click');
                prodDTO.Id = $('#<%=txtId.ClientID%>').val();
                prodDTO.Name = $('#<%=txtName.ClientID%>').val();
                prodDTO.Category = $('#<%=txtCategory.ClientID%>').val();
                prodDTO.Price = $('#<%=txtPrice.ClientID%>').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:65472/api/products',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //4.
                    data: prodDTO,
                    ContentType: 'application/json;utf-8',
                    datatype: 'json'
                }).done(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                }).error(function (err) {
                    console.log("Error " + err.status);
                });
                alert("Post on click");
                return false;
            });

            var products; //global variable products
            function getProducts() {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost:65472/api/products",
                    function (data) {
                        $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.
                        //Assign the return value to products variable
                        products = data;
                        // Loop through the list of products.
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            // Add a table row for the product.
                            var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' + val.Price + '</td>';
                            $('<tr/>', { html: row })  // Append the name.
                                .appendTo($('#products'));
                        });
                        alert('exiting getproducts');
                    });
            };

            //function appendItem() {
            //    var obj = products;
            //    obj.push({ "Id": "4", "Name": "Goya Guava Drink", "Category": "Beverages", "Price": "1.50" });

            //    //if you want to display the change in table then you need to repopulate the table here
            //    $('#products').empty();
            //    // Loop through the list of products.
            //    $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
            //        // Add a table row for the product.
            //        var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' + val.Price + '</td>';
            //        $('<tr/>', { html: row })  // Append the name.
            //            .appendTo($('#products'));
            //    });
            //    return false;
            //};
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h2>Products</h2>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="products">
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr />
            Id:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtId">10</asp:TextBox>
            Name:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName">Test</asp:TextBox>
            Category:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCategory">Test Category</asp:TextBox>
            Price:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrice">5.50</asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="POST" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ProductsController.cs ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

namespace WebForms
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {

        Product[] products = new Product[]
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category =         "Groceries", Price = 1 },
            new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
            new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return product;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
        {
            return products.Where(
                (p) => string.Equals(p.Category, category,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        public string AppendRow([FromBody] YourObjectDto prodDTO)
        {
            var id = prodDTO.Id;
            var name = prodDTO.Name;
            var category = prodDTO.Category;
            var price = prodDTO.Price;
            //new Product { Id = id, Name = name, Category = category, Price = price };


            return "success";
        }

        // POST api/Products
        public Product Post([FromBody]Product prodDTO)
        {
            return prodDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is often a sign that your code threw an exception of some sort that wasn't caught.

Comment: @dwilliss is right. Your Web API configuration and/or routing setup is probably failing so your request isn't even getting to your controller. Try downloading a simple Web API sample project and get it run as-is. Next, add your new controller and test it. That way you eliminate Web API set up issues from your troubleshooting.